# sort numbers by digit

Tags: c++, algorithm

why this code does not work? it does not show me output

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
void Sort(int *arr,int length){
    int *iter=arr;
    char buf[12],buf1[12];
     while ((iter++)< (arr+length)){

          if (iter==arr || (strcmp(itoa(*iter,buf,10),itoa(*(iter-1),buf1,10))>=0)){
       iter++;
          }
          else{
              *iter^=*(iter+1);
              *(iter+1)^=*iter;
              *iter^=*(iter+1);
              iter--;
          }

          }


     }

     int main(){

         int a[]={1,2,10,100,19,21,2,4,31};
         int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
         Sort(a,n);
          for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            std::cout<<a[i]<<"  ";




          return 0;
     }
```

please help

Comment: are you sure it's finishing sorting?

Comment: Don't write your own sort routine; write a comparator, and leverage the STL.

Comment: "Does not work" is *not* an error description.  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: What are you expecting from this line? strcmp(itoa(*iter,buf,10),itoa(*(iter-1),buf1,10)

Comment: Sorry. Forgot that itoa returns the pointer to resulted buffer.

Comment: Don't use such weird swap routines. `std::swap(*iter, *(iter+1));` is a lot shorter and a lot clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the output using gcc 4.5.1:

```
> g++ -o test test.cpp
> test.exe
1  2  10  100  19  21  2  4  31
```

As you can see, it compiles and runs fine in my place. Whether it works like intended is another matter though.

Are you sure you saved your changes before compiling ? What compiler are you using ?

---

Moreover, you should better use a `std::vector` to store the integers and `std::sort` with a custom `comparator` object to do the sort.

Comment: The expected output is 1 10 100 19 2 2 31 4. Sorting by digit.

Comment: @Manoj R: Sure. But the OP states that his example does not output anything at all. So I guess his first problem is to solve this before.

Comment: You don't need a custom comparator. Just use a `std::vector<std::string>`, and sort that. I.e. move the int-to-string conversion before the sort phase.